# How do I use snort on a win-hunt VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, wireshark, snort

On the VM snort is installed with I assume to be all the right auxiliary files and rules. However when I start Snort.exe it instantly starts scanning for network traffic, instead of a pcap file that is supposed to be scanned. I know that there is a command that utilizes a pcap.conf document upon start up but when I put it into the the VMs command terminal it gives me a error saying "snort" is not recognized as a internal or external command. I'm pretty sure its a syntax error but for the life of me I cant seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. Any insight would be helpful! thanks.

I tried changing the line to see if I put a space were it wasn't supposed to be. I figured the path I put didn't track correctly to both files so re typed the whole thing. I even put the pcap file in an easier directory for snort to track but still nothing. I received the same report saying snort, Nano, or even sudo is not recognized. If not that it would be a note saying the path was wrong etc.